# Nativescript concurrency and low latency audio in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, audio, nativescript, low-latency

I have a Nativescript app the targets Android and iOS and produces audio but I want to be able to play concurrent audio files with low latency and at the moment I'm using [nativescript-audio](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio) which doesn't have either of those features.

I found [EZAudio](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-ezaudio) which claims to have low latency but it's only for iOS and I want something for Android as well.

I also found a [nativescript-audio issue](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio/issues/87) requesting those features but it's remained open for a while.

I've seen some Javascript audio libraries like [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) but not sure how to implement them in a Nativescript app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that NativeScript is single-threaded, so you may run into latency when processing real-time data.

Comment: You can of course create a new queue and operate on that.

Comment: @Manoj what do you mean by create a new queue? I'm new to Nativescript and haven't seen anything in documentation about that

Comment: Yes, Of course you can create your own queue and execute in that as you have full access to those native functions. Install tns-platform-declarations plugin which will list all the native apis you have access to within the runtime.